# Nested array while loop

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I am using a nested while loop to  create a nested array that will look like this:

```
[276] => Array
    (
        [0] => 302
    )

[279] => Array
    (
        [0] => 290
        [1] => 291
        [1] => 223
```

But for some reason I am only getting one nested array showing up under  279 but I know the
data I am querying is returning at least 12 records that should be under the 279 array.

Here is my while loop code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $term_id = $row[term_id];

    // Look up Children Categories
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy wpt where parent = $row[term_id]";

    // execute query:
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

    // fetch results:
    $count_2 = "0";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $term_id2 = $row2['term_id'];
        $arr[$term_id] = array($count_2 => $row2[term_id]); 
        $count_2++;
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong? Its like the nested array resets each time so I just get one record under the nested array.

Comment: Dude, you should be banned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552456/smarty-nested-foreach-loop-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$arr[$term_id] = array($count_2 => $row2[term_id]);
```

This assigns a new array to `$arr[$term_id]`. It does not append to an existing array if you already put items there in a previous iteration of the loop, it overwrites it, or "resets it" as you put it. You told it to do that.

```
$arr[$term_id][$count_2] = $row2[term_id];
```